# multioutput='variance_weighted' in scikit-learn r2_score: what does it calculate?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am using scikit-learn r2_score function and I would like to understand what the option 'variance_weighted' calculates. In the documentation [page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) it tells: *Scores of all outputs are averaged, weighted by the variances of each individual output*. Does it mean that the output is a weighted average whose weights are the variances of data of which score has to be calculated ?

For example:

```
>>> y_true = [[0.5, 1], [-1, 1], [7, -6]]
>>> y_pred = [[0, 2], [-1, 2], [8, -5]]
>>> r2_score(y_true, y_pred, multioutput='variance_weighted')
```

Here the variance for the first *individual output* means the variance of [0.5, 1, 0, 2] ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The 'variance_weighted' option means that the output is a weighted average whose weights are the variances of the true data (the first argument to `r2_score`). In your example, the first weight is the variance of `[0.5, -1, 7]` and the second weight is the variance of `[1, 1, -6]`. See this demonstration, which adds to your example:

```py
y_true = [[0.5, 1], [-1, 1], [7, -6]]
y_pred = [[0, 2], [-1, 2], [8, -5]]

y_true_var = np.var(y_true, axis=0)
print(y_true_var)
# [12.05555556 10.88888889]

# manually compute the variance-weighted r2 score using
# the raw r2 outputs and the variance of the true values
print(np.average(r2_score(y_true, y_pred, multioutput='raw_values'), weights=y_true_var))
# 0.9382566585956416

print(r2_score(y_true, y_pred, multioutput='variance_weighted'))
# 0.9382566585956417
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However I do not understand one thing: how can the number of weights be different from the number of r2 scores calculated ? I mean: it says that *scores of all outputs are averaged*. So in this case we should have 3  r2 scores and 2 weights... how can you make a weighted average in this way ? Moreover how can the weights, calculated as you did, be associated to each r2 score ?

Comment: Your `y_true` and y_pred` variables have shape (3, 2). The [documentation for the r2_score function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) says that the input arguments, when 2-dimensional, correspond to `(n_samples, n_outputs)`. So you have 3 samples and 2 outputs. The `r2_score` function will then return 2 r2 scores by default, which aligns with the 2 weights that you get from computing the variance of `y_true` along the first axis.

Comment: I did not think to check the length of r2_score array when the multioutput parameter is set to 'raw_values' indeed. I was assuming it was 3 in this case. So the first r2 score value when `multioutput='raw_values'`  in `r2_score` function is the r2 score calculated between first elements of all the sub-lists? So for example in this case, it is the r2 score calculated between [0.5,-1, 7] and [0,-1,8] ?

Comment: Yes I checked and it is so. At this point I have a very last question: why did they choose the variances of `y_true` as weights ?

Comment: Maybe because if you have higher variance in true values, the r2 score calculated between the true and predicted values has a higher importance ?

Comment: That would be my guess as well, but I don't know and I cannot find any good references about it. At one point, `multioutput='variance_weighted'` was the default. It changed early on in scikit-learn development (see this issue that refers to the change https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4728) and it may be being kept around for legacy support.